# CalDAV client's Report method not requesting for the new event data

Tags: http, webdav, caldav

I am currently working on development of a caldav synchronization server layer for my calendar application. I am able to answer all the initial requested by the calendar client and currently stuck with the REPORT method.

When PROPFIND is done on Calendar, it asks for CTag and Sync-Token. I do answer this query by providing a CTag and Sync-Token (currently to mock the server, I dynamically generate these value and serve the client).

In the next query,  the requested method is REPORT on the calendar as shown below:

**Request from client:**

```
REPORT URI  /users/admin%40a.de/calendar/ PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
----------------------------------------
Accept-encoding  gzip, deflate
Accept  */*
Connection  keep-alive
Prefer  return=minimal
Host  **************
Brief  t
User-agent  Mac+OS+X/10.10.5 (14F27) CalendarAgent/316.1
Depth  1
Authorization  Basic YWRtaW5AYS5kZTpwYXNz
Accept-language  en-us
Content-type  text/xml
Content-length  260
Request body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A:sync-collection xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:sync-token>http://calserver.org/ns/sync-token/1</A:sync-token>
  <A:sync-level>1</A:sync-level>
  <A:prop>
    <A:getcontenttype/>
    <A:getetag/>
  </A:prop>
</A:sync-collection>
```

**Response from the Server:**

**Response header**

```
Content-type: text/calendar;  charset=UTF-8
Connection:   keep-alive
Date  Thu, 17 Dec 2015 19:35:40 GMT
Transfer-encoding  chunked
Http/1.1  207 Multi-Status
```

**Response body**

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D=\"DAV:\" xmlns:C=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav\" xmlns:E=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav\">
<D:response>
 <D:propstat>
  <D:href>/calendar/2601ddd19c1001.ics</D:href>
  <D:prop>
         <D:getcontenttype>text/calendar</D:getcontenttype>
         <D:getetag>"334411222s12"</D:getetag>
  </D:prop>
  <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
 </D:propstat>
</D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

Now my question is, In the server-response, I answer the REPORT method that a new event has been created by providing a new ETag value, but the data is not requested by the Client ??

How and when should I serve the calendar data of the new event and what would be the request from client ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Content-type should not be `text/xml`, It should be `text/calendar`.
- The etag needs to be surrounded by double-quotes.
- I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea to use a `+` in the uri the way you did. If you want to encode a space, use `%20` instead, but it's probably even better to completely avoid any sort of special encoding.
- The response to a sync-collection report also must have the current sync-token in the response body. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578#section-6.4

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yep I changed content type to icalendar and also enclosed etag within double quotes. But no luck!. The plus sign  "+" is not in the etag and is just part of the code to dynamically get fresh value to be appended with the etag value (for testing purpose).

Comment: removed those plus sign from question to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Hi, sorry I was wrong. The content type should be `text/calendar` not `text/icalendar`, and I added another bullet point to my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, update contenttype and also added current sync-token value. But still the next question "calendar-data" is not being asked.

Comment: @Hoysala Note that the content-type of the HTTP response itself should be application/xml (text/xml is also acceptable), whereas the D:getcontenttype value should be "text/calendar" as Evert has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Rather confused by the multiple edits but the content-type in the response **header** should definitely be text/xml

Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8